# Choose from multiple imported XSLTs to apply

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to choose an XSLT file to apply to my entire XML input file. I am not sure how to do that. What I am trying to do is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:import href="a.xslt" />
  <xsl:import href="b.xslt" />      
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="(/*[local-name()='1'])>
        ---------Apply file a.xslt here----------
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="(/*[local-name()='2'])>
        ----------Apply file b.xslt here-------------
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to apply different XSLT files based on my XML input. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 you can do this directly using the fn:transform() function.

If you don't have access to XSLT 3.0, the usual solution would be to use modes: define the template rules in a.xslt and b.xslt with different modes, and apply templates in the appropriate mode.

(Incidentally, the `local-name()` of an element will never be numeric.)

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I ended up doing since I did not have access to XSLT 3.0.

I changed the names of the elements/files to numerics and alphabets to avoid confusion.